# Entity Framework Core can't map official types to PostgreSQL columns

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I downloaded a sample database for Postgres (v14) ([dvdrental](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-sample-database/)) so I could follow some SQL tutorials. I wanted to create an ASP.NET Core (5) Web API for that database, so using scaffolding, I created the entities based on the database tables and columns, then after some minor changes, I wanted to create a new migration.

That step failed though, as I'm getting two errors (so far) regarding the data types.

> The property 'Film.Fulltext' is of type 'NpgsqlTsVector' which is not supported by the current database provider. Either change the property CLR type or ignore the property using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

I tried to use `[NotMapped]`, but got the same error. I also tried to specify

```
[Column(Typename = "tsvector")]
```

which is the official type mapping according to https://www.npgsql.org/doc/types/basic.html, but for some reason, EF core seems to ignore it completely and gives the same error.

> The property 'Film.SpecialFeatures' could not be mapped because it is of type 'string[]', which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property, or ignore it using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'

Which is, again, weird, as the Postgres websites says

```
public string[] Tags { get; set; }
```

The provider will create text[] columns for the above property..

So basically EF Core throws errors about something that is the officially recommended way of doing it, so I have no idea why these errors even occur or how I could solve them.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: If tsvector doesn't work, and you're definitely using the latest version of the Postgresql EF driver, and the features are definitely supported in .NET Core and not just .NET Framework, you probably want to raise that as a bug with Postgresql or ask them directly for help.

Comment: Are you using the Npgsql library?

Comment: Both types are supported (at least by latest EFC 5.0/6.0 provider). (1) What EFC version are you using? (2) Have you configured your context for PostgreSQL, e.g. `UseNpgsql(...)`?

Comment: I am using Npgsql library, I'm using EF Core 5.0.1, Npgsql 5.0.1.1, and yes, I used `UseNpgsql()` in the Startup file

Comment: All I can say is that I tested using (referencing) `Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL` package  versions 5.0.10 and 6.0.0, with entity having `NpgsqlTsVector` and `string[]` type properties, and both were mapped correctly (no exceptions) without anything special (neither data annotation nor fluent configuration).

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm getting something similar with a type mapped to jsonb, that was working fine and now for some reason is giving me this error.